# using flycheck with compile_commands.json

Tags: emacs, flycheck

I've looked around at some open question, but I cannot figure out how to use `flycheck-clangcheck` mode to read the include dirs from the `compile_commands.json` db.

I currently have a largish c++ project. Almost every file would choke on the first `#include <some_package>` line, and flycheck would not reveal any other errors.

I ended up finding `flycheck-clangcheck`, and I setup the package per the README, but I *cannot* get the program to work.

Now, when I open the project, I do not see the flycheck red underline error, but I do see the following error message:

`Error while checking syntax automatically: (file-missing "Opening input file" "No such file or directory" "/compile_commands.json")`

I have tried modifying:
- `flycheck-clangcheck-build-path` in dir-locals.el as well as in my global emacs config
- `flycheck-clangcheck-dbname` to point directly to the db path.

Does anyone know how I can easily integrate flycheck with the `compile_commands.json` db?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`flycheck-clangcheck-build-path` must be set as a string with double ticks eg `"/home/user/project/"`. flycheck-clangcheck is not controling variable type.